PyPDF internal Link Annotation Issue
i am trying to add a link to a pdf document currently its set up to eventually loop through and add multiple annotations to point to many different pages but as of right now i just need to get the annotation to wordk hardcoded on 1 file before i complete the loop.
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader
from pypdf.annotations import Link as pdf_link
from pypdf.generic import Fit,NumberObject

def add_links_to_pdf(pdf_path,page_link,link_locations):
    # Read the PDF
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
    writer = PdfWriter()

    for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
        page = reader.pages[page_num]

        for link in link_locations:
            if link[0] == page_num:
# Create the link annotation
                link_annotation = pdf_link(
                    rect=(50, 550, 200, 650),
                    target_page_index=0,
                    fit=Fit(fit_type="/FitH", fit_args=(123,)),
                )
                writer.add_annotation(page_number=0,annotation=link_annotation)
        # Add the annotation to the page
        # Add the modified page to the writer
        writer.add_page(page)


    # Write the output to a new file
    with open("E:\Work Folder\PDF Bookmark+Combiner\Test2.pdf", "wb") as output_file:
        writer.write(output_file)

link_data = [
    (0, 100, 750, 50, 700)  # (page_number, x1, width, top, height)
]

#
add_links_to_pdf("E:\Work Folder\PDF Bookmark+Combiner\Test.pdf",2,link_data)

i tried this and i used a python debugger to step through it. currently the line below is causing the error.
writer.add_annotation(page_number=0,annotation=link_annotation)

the error message is below
Exception has occurred: IndexError
sequence index out of range
  File "E:\Work Folder\PDF Bookmark+Combiner\PDF_functions.py", line 119, in add_links_to_pdf
    writer.add_annotation(page_number=0,annotation=link_annotation)
  File "E:\Work Folder\PDF Bookmark+Combiner\PDF_functions.py", line 134, in <module>
    add_links_to_pdf("E:\Work Folder\PDF Bookmark+Combiner\Test.pdf",2,link_data)
IndexError: sequence index out of range

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

@KJthank you very much the issue was i hadnt yet added the page to writer.
